# How to animate logo image from right to left infinite horizontal?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have more than 10 logo images. On page load, I have to display only 6 logos and remaining logos will slide from right to left side infinite horizontally.

Would you help me out in keyframes and CSS?

I found the example
https://codepen.io/mdashikar/pen/VWPvgE
but not 100% for me. If you notice that image is a slide from right to left side and wait for few seconds and again slider. I need image should slide continue without stop.

```css
.logo_slider {}
.logo_slider ul { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.logo_slider ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.logo_slider ul li a img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
} 

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from { right: 0px;  }
  to   { left: 200px; }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
  from { right:0px;   }
  to   { left: 200px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo_slider">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Android_O_Preview_Logo.png"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: left/right works only wih positionned element

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I found the example https://codepen.io/mdashikar/pen/VWPvgE but not 100% for me. If you notice that image is a slide from right to left side and wait for few seconds and again slider. I need image should slide continue without stop.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
.logo_slider {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo_slider ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.logo_slider ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.logo_slider ul li a img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.logo_slider ul li:nth-child(1n+7) a img {
  -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 100vw;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: 100vw;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Also look at my codepen: https://codepen.io/zothynine/pen/VQyzQZ

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to display first 6 logos on page log which is working in your code but Now I have to slider each logo one by one from right to left. for example https://codepen.io/mdashikar/pen/VWPvgE

Comment: In above example one image is the slide from right to left. Just notice that image is slide left side and wait for few seconds and then again sliding. I need to continue slide infinite like a marquee.

Comment: I updated my pen. Can you have a look, if that is clooser to your needs?

Comment: Yes, I need like this only but you added 30 logo images, and it does not slide till 30 once reached till the end then again I have to slide from one

Comment: Yes I know, sorry for that. I was in kind of a hurry. I wanted to find out if this solution is going the right direction. I will update my pen asap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work

```
// Fetch variables
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var bodyHeight = $(document).height() - windowHeight;
var scrollPercentage = (scrollTop / bodyHeight);

// if the scroll is more than 90% from the top, load more content.
if(scrollPercentage > 0.9) {
    // Load content
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you share the whole code or snippet? because It's hard to understand for me.

Comment: Just write your required code in load content section.